# Specify request body in Google API calls (using Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to call Google API method *drive.files.insert* to create a folder in Google Drive with a request like this (using Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript):

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.insert({'convert': 'false', 'ocr': 'false'});
request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
```

The problem is that I need to specify some params in the request body, for example:

```
{
    "title":"testFolder",
    "description":"hello world",
    "mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

But I cannot figure it out how to specify these parameters with the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript. Is there any suggestion of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `body` field. [See this example](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/requestWithBody.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much, so we need to use `gapi.client.request` if we want to send a request with body

Comment: Is there a solution without using gapi.client.request?

Answer (score 9):

Not necessarily `gapi.client.request` with `body` field.

You may try `gapi.client.drive.files.insert({'convert': 'false', 'ocr': 'false','resource': resource})` where `resource` is actually what you want to send, e.g.

```
resource = {
    "title":"testFolder",
    "description":"hello world",
    "mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

I have not verified that but I have tried exactly the same scenario with sending request body for creating Google Task list (gapi.client.tasks.tasklists.insert)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Same thing applies for analytics api that needs to upload a request body. So for some reason they decided "resource" was a good keyword to delimit request body but didn't care about documenting it well.

Answer (score 4):

Use the "resource" keyword to send the body.